# Nested loops to iterate through every factor and generate every combination of plots in r/ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate multiple plots using ggplot that exhausts every combination of factors (as x-axis and as color) against the response (as y-axis) in a single data frame.  One small caveat is that I want to plot categorical factors as factors and ordinal factors as numeric (so I basically ordered all the numeric columns at the end of my column names array--I have some ugly logic inside the for loop which handles that).

Here is the code I have made so far:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    df <- mpg


    column_names<- names(df)

    #categorical factors: "manufacturer", "model", "cyl", "trans", "drv"  
    categoricalFactors <- c(column_names[1],column_names[2], column_names[5], column_names[6], column_names[7])

    #ordinal factors: "displ", "year"
    numericalFactors <- c(column_names[3],column_names[4])

    #combines above such that the numerical factors are at the end, starting from index 6
    all_factors <- c(categoricalFactors,numericalFactors)

    #responses: "cty", "hwy"
    responses <- c(column_names[8],column_names[9])

    for (i in 1:length(responses)){ #iterate through all the responses
      for(j in 1:length(all_factors)){ #iterate through all the factors (for y-axis)
        for(k in 1:length(all_factors)){ #iterate through all the factors (for color or lty or group)

          if(j!=k){ #just to make sure I didn't plot the y-axis and color together
            if(j<6 & k<6){ #indicates j and k are both categorial, use as.factor for both
              ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(all_factors[j]), responses[i], color=as.factor(all_factors[k]))) + geom_line()
              #also tried:
              #ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(df[,all_factors[j]]), df[,responses[i]], color=as.factor(df[,all_factors[k]]))) + geom_line()
            }
            else if(j<6 & k>=6){ #indicates j is categorical (as.factor) and k is ordinal (as.numeric)
              ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(all_factors[j]), responses[i], color=as.as.numeric(as.character((all_factors[k]))))) + geom_line()
            }
            else if(j>=6 & k<6){#indicates j is ordinal (as.numeric) and k is categorical (as.factor)
              ggplot(df, aes(as.numeric(as.character((all_factors[j]))), responses[i], color=as.factor(all_factors[k]))) + geom_line()
            }
            else if(j>=6 & k>=6){#indicates j and k are both ordinal  (as.numeric)
              ggplot(df, aes(as.numeric(as.character(all_factors[j])), responses[i], color=as.numeric(as.character(all_factors[k])))) + geom_line()
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried accessing the column by reference by specifying it as df[,all_factors[1]], but it doesn't work on ggplot being iterated over.  For example:

```
    ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(df[,all_factors[j]]), df[,responses[i]], color=as.factor(df[,all_factors[k]]))) + geom_line()
```

Doesn't plot anything.  But adding literal indecies and trying the command into the console does work:

```
    >>ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(df[,all_factors[1]]), df[,responses[1]], color=as.factor(df[,all_factors[2]]))) + geom_line()
```

**EDIT: Figured out that I should add a print statement before each ggplot line**

Second question still holds: is there a more elegant way to get this done?

Comment: Check `aes_string` http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/aes_string.html

Comment: tried aes_string with no luck :-/